# Debug 32bit application on 64bit OS using kernel debugger

Tags: debugging, windbg, postmortem-debugging

I have the following scenario:

I am attached with the kernel debugger (Windbg) to a Hyper-V machine running **Windows 10 64bit**.
My process-to-be-debugged is a **32bit user-mode process** which sometimes hangs the machine (it communicates with a minifilter), and therefore I cannot use user-mode debugger or remote debugger.

Now I have a symbols server, I know the process and the thread I want to investigate, how do I:

1. View the callstack for this thread only
2. Load symbols for my modules

Bonus question: For some reason, I have many instances of my program. Except the "active" one, the rest are not visible in Process Explorer, have no threads and 0 Handle count. What could cause this?

Things I tried:

```
!process ffffe08620a30800 7
(view all process threads)
...
       THREAD **ffffe0862212f800**  Cid 08a0.1cfc  Teb: 0000000000d6e000 Win32Thread: 0000000000000000 RUNNING on processor 0
        Not impersonating
        DeviceMap                 ffffcb0a55817c30
        Owning Process            ffffe08620a30800       Image:         avguard.exe
        Attached Process          N/A            Image:         N/A
        Wait Start TickCount      27338460       Ticks: 1 (0:00:00:00.015)
        Context Switch Count      2999214        IdealProcessor: 0             
        UserTime                  **00:17:51.125**
        KernelTime                00:06:14.671
        Win32 Start Address 0x00000000741bbfb4
        Stack Init ffffb481db842dd0 Current ffffb481db842a10
        Base ffffb481db843000 Limit ffffb481db83d000 Call 0
        Priority 8 BasePriority 8 UnusualBoost 0 ForegroundBoost 0 IoPriority 2 PagePriority 5
        Child-SP          RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
        ffffb481`db842c40 00000000`77b1222c : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceExit+0x2f (TrapFrame @ ffffb481`db842c40)
        00000000`0333ed18 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : wow64cpu!CpupSyscallStub+0xc
...
```

This thread is the one I want to investigate. It has a high processor usage, as visible in bold: User Time: 17 mins. However the stack is not helpful.
Then I did:

```
.thread /p /r /w ffffe0862212f800
Implicit thread is now ffffe086`2212f800
Implicit process is now ffffe086`20a30800
.cache forcedecodeuser done
Loading User Symbols
.ModLoad: 00000000`009b0000 00000000`00a25000   C:\Program Files (x86)\my process.exe
.ModLoad: 00007ffb`67e20000 00007ffb`67ff1000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
.ModLoad: 00000000`778d0000 00000000`77922000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\wow64.dll
.ModLoad: 00000000`77850000 00000000`778c7000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\wow64win.dll
.ModLoad: 00000000`77b10000 00000000`77b1a000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\wow64cpu.dll

The context is partially valid. Only x86 user-mode context is available.
x86 context set
1: kd:x86> kb
  *** Stack trace for last set context - .thread/.cxr resets it
ChildEBP          RetAddr           Args to Child                                         
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
db842cc0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 **0x819613ca**
```

What is this address 0x819613ca?
How can I extract the module in which this belongs? Or extract a meaningfull callstack?
How can I proceed now further with my investigation?

Comment: " I have many instances of my program" - do you mean you have many kernel process objects? They could be old and wait for reuse.

Comment: It is possible, but why only for my process?

Comment: This is similar to [zombie processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) in Linux. Probably somebody still holds a reference to these `EPROCESS`s. You said the handle count was zero, but not the pointer count. (This can also happen if there's an IRP that didn't complete or got canceled, and maybe in other scenarios.)

Comment: To get symbols for user mode processes working you need to enable a GlobalFlag called ["Enable loading of kernel debugger symbols"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542932(v=vs.85).aspx), or `ksl` (**k**ernel **s**ymbol **l**oading). Did you enable that? If not, try doing [`!gflag +ksl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563176(v=vs.85).aspx) and then `.reload /user`. On the other hand, I see the .ModLoad events, so I'm not sure that's the problem...